# Determing Missing Compiler / Files

Tags: apt, package-management, files

I am very new to Linux.

My question is this : 
I have installed CodeBlocks IDE, and tried to compile a simple "Hello World" program to no avail.

After researching and looking at the output errors in CodeBlocks I found that it was a compiler RELATED issue. From that and looking here and there, I found here in Stack Exchange the solution was pretty simple : 
All I had to do was to type into terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

My question is this : 
How can one determine what is missing and thus type the correct thing/title after sudo apt-get install [correct title?]

Comment: You need to update Your question with all error messages that You got during the compilation of the program.

Comment: No I do not think you understand me : Mine is a very generic question :